# PHP Insert '&' / and text symbol in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to insert the `&` symbol in my PHP code but instead its being converted into ASCII `&amp;`.

Below is my code:

```
$symbolAnd= '&';
echo $symbolAnd;
foreach ($clientLists as $clientList =>$clientValue){
    //Get values
    echo  $clientList .' - '.$clientValue['client-pass'] . '<br/>';

    include('index.php?client='.$clientList.$symbolAnd.'pass='.$clientValue['client-pass']);
}//foreach ($clientLists as $clientList){
```

I am getting this error in my `error_log`;

`PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'index.php?client=john-jones&amp;pass=123456' for inclusion`

Comment: Whatever you're triyng to do this will not work this way.

Comment: Hi, how can I go about it please? Thanks.

Comment: try using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. It displays an `&amp;` because the output of error.log is what should be outputted to the user in HTML if error were displayed. The real problem here is that you are trying to include a file and passing GET parameters, but that however is not possible. When you `include` (although the same happens for all its variants like `require` and `include_once`) a file, you have to see it as a copy and paste of that file into your current PHP file. You are trying to get from your filesystem the file with the name being `index.php?client=WhateverClientListIs&pass=WhateverClientPassIs`, which does not exist!

To fix this, you can do the following:

```
 $_GET['client'] = $clientList;
 $_GET['pass'] = $clientValue['client-pass'];
 include('index.php');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't use `$_GET` as the values are inside a multi dimensional array which are outputted using a foreach loop

Comment: And what? On each iteration set `GET` variables, or use `global` keyword.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You should be able to include your file this way, setting your GET values manually.

Comment: if allow_url_include is true you can include through HTTP by using an complet url infront.see doc page -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php note your code may be less Secure

Answer (score 1):

Whatever symbols you put into your filename (`&` or `&amp;`) this approach will not work as you expect unless you really have files which names are

```
index.php?client=client1&password=1234
index.php?client=client2&password=123123
index.php?client=client3&password=qwerty
```

I mean real files. Cause `include` includes file by **name**.
And if you want to include `index.php` you should `include('index.php')`